# Add line from point to x-axis and bold label of him

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart.js in my website
When hovering over a point in the graph, I need to draw a line that goes down to the x-axis and bold his label
like this:
[chart][1]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom plugin for this, see live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      selector: {
        color: 'blue',
        width: 2,
        // If canvas has a different backgroundColor set this to match
        boxColor: 'white'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'selector',
    beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
      // Return if no hover
      if (chart._active.length === 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Set all variables needed
      const activeEl = chart._active[0].element;
      const labelItem = chart.scales.x._labelItems[chart._active[0].index];
      const {
        ctx,
        scales: {
          y
        }
      } = chart;
      const metrics = ctx.measureText(labelItem.label);
      const labelWidth = metrics.width;
      const labelHeight = metrics.fontBoundingBoxAscent + metrics.fontBoundingBoxDescent;

      // Draw white box over old label
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = opts.boxColor || '#FFFFFF';
      ctx.fillRect((labelItem.translation[0] - labelWidth / 2), labelItem.translation[1], labelWidth, labelHeight);
      ctx.restore();

      // Draw new text on canvas
      ctx.save();
      ctx.font = Chart.helpers.toFontString(Object.assign(labelItem.font, {
        style: 'bold'
      }));
      ctx.fillText(labelItem.label, (labelItem.translation[0] - labelWidth / 2), labelItem.translation[1] + labelItem.textOffset)
      ctx.restore();

      // Draw vertical line down from point
      ctx.save();
      ctx.lineWidth = opts.width || 1;
      ctx.strokeStyle = opts.color || 'black';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(activeEl.x, activeEl.y);
      ctx.lineTo(activeEl.x, y.getPixelForValue(y.min));
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I still have a problem. the _active  property isnt a konwn property of chart. Does anyone know why it's happening?

Comment: Might be because you are using version 2 of the lib so you will need to either update to use this plugin or see what is different and adjust the plugin

Comment: Really thanks for the reply. The answer is perfect and it works for me